# Static header (including NAV and other DIVs)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a static header that doesn't move when scrolling the page (below HTML).

```
<header id="header">

<div class="nav-menu" id="mynav">
  <div id="nav-menu-container">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-active">home</li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="books.html">books</a></li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="scene">
  <div id="animation"></div>

</div>
  </header>

<main>
</main>
```

I have tried adding the below CSS. This makes the header static, but, it pushes it to the top left of the browser. Therefore, the content inside the main tag starts at the top-middle of the browser.

```
#header{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index:1;}
```

**Like this:**

|Header||Main|

**Instead of:**

|Header|

|Main|

JSFIDDLE
https://jsfiddle.net/dy8gaL4j/1/

How can I make the header stay at the top (above the main tag) whilst also being static - only the main content will scroll.

Thanks

Comment: Your demo code has CSS applied to a #header element that's missing from the HTML you've posted, which will make this hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: @delinear updated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So it's top left and doesn't scroll...what is the *actual* problem? "Rest of the content"...what content? There's none of that in your supplied code.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D hope I have clarified enough

Comment: What is the CSS of the `<main>`? Fixing the header would not cause the main to be alongside it.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have added a JSFiddle - sorry I am fairly new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood what you want, so if this is not the right solution, please let me know. I suppose you want fixed full-width header with scrollable body bellow.
I would try to add left and right parameters and set them to 0, and then position body content a bit bellow it (you'll have to adjust `margin-top` value).
Here is my example

```css
#header{
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
z-index:1;
background: #aaa;
}

main{
  margin-top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">

<div class="nav-menu" id="mynav">
  <div id="nav-menu-container">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-active">home</li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="books.html">books</a></li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="scene">
  <div id="animation"></div>

</div>
  </header>

<main>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
line of text <br>
</main>
```

Comment: No problem. 
I hope this helped, but I also hope this question will help you write questions that will provide faster and better answers next time. I am sure everyone appreciates your willingness to edit question as many times as possible until it looks fine.
I hope I will see more of your questions, and hopefully answers too.